# Gyroscopic effect with multiple parts rotating

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

I understand how a basic gyroscope work and how to work out the precession.

Now consider the following. The spinning mass of a basic gyroscope is connected via a gear to another rotating mass, which spins along a different axis (say at 90 deg).

Forgetting about the gyroscopic effects for a bit, if I wanted to analyse the system, I might compute the reflected inertia (from each of inertias and the gear ratio) and then derive the equations of motions etc to see how the system behaves. Now say I wanted to take into account the gyroscopic effect as the masses start to spin. Would I compute the gyroscopic torques of each mass independently using its own inertia, or would I use the reflected inertias?

Thanks,
Cyril

Comment: The gyroscopic effects will add vectorially.

Comment: I don't think you can use reflected inertia since the "direction" information (present in the axis of rotation of each rotating part) is lost. Perhaps you can add more details to your question. Possibly a diagram with minimum number of rotating masses to illustrate the problem. As well as the equations you plan to use.